# Can I write an Abel Summation Formula for this?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, summation, change-of-variable, summation-method, mixing-variables

Given appropriate constraints, and a continuously differentiable real-valued function $\phi (x)$, the Abel Summation Formula (Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula)) can be written as

$$\sum _{k=1}^x \phi (k) = \lfloor x\rfloor  \phi (x)-\int_1^x \lfloor
   u\rfloor  \phi '(u) \, du$$

Is it possible to generate a similar ASF for the sum $\sum _{i=1}^x \phi (x-i)$? It may be a very simple question (or it may not!), but I keep getting confused by the mix of variables and dummy variables, and defining the sum's limit. As a result, I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^x \phi(x-i)
= \phi(x-1) + \phi(x-2) + \cdots + \phi(1) + \phi(0)
= \sum_{i=0}^{x-1} \phi(i)
$$
for which it is easy to derive a suitable formula (or just reference the article to find),
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{x-1} \phi(i)
= \lfloor x \rfloor \phi(x-1) - \int_0^{x-1} \lfloor u+1 \rfloor \phi'(u) \, \mathrm{d}u
$$

Comment: Thanks @PrincessEev. You are of course right - I have no good justification for being so muddled!