# Follow-up question on Abel Summation

Tags: summation, change-of-variable, summation-method, mixing-variables

This is a follow-up to a much simpler question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735379/can-i-write-an-abel-summation-formula-for-this), which @PrincessEev answered promptly and perfectly. She showed me how to rewrite the sum $\sum _{i=1}^x \phi (x-i)$ in such a way that Abel Summation could be applied, to obtain

$$\sum _{i=1}^x \phi (x-i) = \lfloor x \rfloor \phi(x-1) - \int_0^{x-1} \lfloor u+1 \rfloor \phi'(u) \, \mathrm{d}u$$

Here is a harder problem - I think. And once again, I don't really know where to start. Let $1 \le j \le x$ be a constant positive integer. Can one apply Abel Summation to the sum  $\sum _{i=1}^x \phi (x - i j)$? If so, how?

**CLARIFICATION / UPDATE**

I initially added follow-up material here asking what I was doing wrong in implementing @junjios's answer. The fault was mine and was a coding error in my use of Mathematica.

Since it has no bearing on @junjios's correct answer, I have deleted those elements of this post, to avoid confusing new readers. If you are puzzled over some of the posts in the comments section, this is the explanation.

Comment: The formula works for me: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oynnlokdsv

Comment: Sorry, do you want $\phi$ to be $\sin^2(x)$ or $\sin(x^2)$? Just asking, because I don't understand your last equality and also not how Mathematica arrives at the given expression.

Comment: Apologies @junios, I’m away from my computer until later. I meant $\sin (x^2)$ but until I can get back to Mathematica, I won’t know if I made a typo putting stuff into the software or rewriting it into TeX …

Comment: Humble apologies, @junjios. The error was entirely mine and was due to poor coding. Mathematica was calculating the derivative $\phi' (x-u j)$ with respect to $\$ not $u$. I will change the 'update' section of my post to remove uncertainties, and I will of course mark this as answered. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\geq 1$ and $j\in\mathbb{R}$ be fixed. (Note: There are no further conditions on $j$!)

We define: $\psi(y):=\phi(x-yj)$. Clearly, $\psi$ is continuously differentiable, so we can apply the Abel summation formula to obtain
$$\sum_{i=1}^x\phi(x-ij)=\sum_{i=1}^x\psi(i)=\lfloor x\rfloor\psi(x)-\int_1^x\lfloor u\rfloor\psi'(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\\=\lfloor x\rfloor\phi(x(1-j))+j\int_1^x\lfloor u\rfloor\phi'(x-uj)\,\mathrm{d}u.$$

#### Generalisation:

More generally, given any (further) continuously differentiable function $f$ (possibly depending on $x$), we may write
$$\sum_{i=1}^x\phi(f(i))=\lfloor x\rfloor\phi(f(x))-\int_1^x\lfloor u\rfloor\phi'(f(u))f'(u)\,\mathrm{d}u.$$

Comment: Hi @junjios. This is great - but could you please take a look at my update above? I'm doing something wrong!

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward I did and added a comment above. I cannot pinpoint a specific mistake yet, but could you have messed up $\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin(x^2)$ somehow?